# LInked List flattening in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am writing this code to practice linked lists. The goal is to flatten the linked list. Can anyone help in pointing out the mistake's here ? THanks.

(LInk flattening theory: Something like this:http://code-forum.blogspot.com/2010/12/function-to-flatten-list-into-single.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct Node {
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
    struct Node *child;
    int          value;
} Node;

void print_list(Node* root) {
  while (root) {
    printf("%c ", root->value);

    if(root->child){    
        printf("%c ", root->child->value);  
    }

    root = root->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void append(Node *child, Node **tail){
    Node *curNode = child;
    (*tail)->next = curNode;
    curNode->prev = *tail;
    *tail = curNode;    
}   

void flatten_list(Node *head, Node **tail) {

    printf("in flatten function now\n");
    Node *curNode = head;
    while (curNode) {
        if (curNode->child){
            printf("current node has a child\n");
            append(curNode->child,tail);
            curNode->child= NULL;   
        }
        curNode = curNode->next;        
    }   
}


main()
{
    Node g = { 0, 0,  0, '1' };
    Node e = { 0, 0, 0, '9'   };        
//  Node f = { 0, &e, 0, '8' };
    Node d = { 0,  0, 0, '6'  };
    Node c = { &d, 0, &g ,'5' };
    Node b = { &c, 0, 0 , '3' };
    Node a = { &b, 0, &e, '4' };


    Node* root = &a;    
    Node *tail = &g;
    printf("Unflattened List:\n");
    print_list(root);   
    flatten_list(root,&tail);
    printf("Flattened List:\n");
    print_list(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless you tell us the symptoms, probably not.

Comment: in `void flatten_list(Node *head, Node **tail)`: if head == 0: curNode = 0; while(0) nothing; curNode = 0-> next// bad

Comment: Also, put curNode->child = 0 between calling 'append()' and 'curNode = curNode->next; '

Comment: Does this even compile? The second argument of append should be `Node**`, but in `flatten_list`, `&tail` is a `Node***` pointer.

Comment: You need to flat list until there are no `Node`s having a child, thus `while(curNode)` is definitely wrong. So, define a function that will check is list flat or no.(Need to walk through list and check is there any Node with a child)

Answer (score 1):

One problem is you print_list routine assumes that the list is already flat. So it's not going to be very helpful in determining the difference between a flattened and unflattened list.

Another problem is that when you flatten a child you don't null the child pointer. I would expect to see something like

```
    if (curNode->child){
        printf("current node has a child\n");
        append(curNode->child,&tail);   
        curNode->child = NULL;
    }
```

Another problem is that because your flattening procedure appends child nodes to the end of the list is inevitably reorders the list. This is not what a flattening function should to. For instance if you flatten

(1 2 (3 4 5) 6 7)

then you should get

(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)

whereas your code (if I understand it right) will give

(1 2 6 7 3 4 5)

That's enough for now, good luck!

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Add the child nodes to the end. And the print would work because it would simply print the child nodes at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone else, I'm not sure what your problem is (what do you mean by "flatten"?), but this is a bug:

```
append(curNode->child,&tail);
```

should be

```
append(curNode->child,tail);
```

Comment: (LInk flattening theory: Something like this:http://code-forum.blogspot.com/2010/12/function-to-flatten-list-into-single.html)